# How to install PHP library using Drush

Tags: drush

My module depends on a PHP library (sites/all/libraries/xyz/xyz-library.php). It doesn't install unless the external library `libraries/xyz/xyz-library.php` is in place. Is there a way to install the library using Drush first and then install the module?

Comment: I am not sure if you need to install library module, but your best bet could be to go to the folder and `curl` or `wget` the library (in case if you have the link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use drush make for this purpose. Drush make files can add in third-party dependencies which can be useful for just this kind of thing. Unless you intend to share this module with the community, in which case, you can issue a wget from the module itself similar to how other contrib modules do it. (See JW Player for an older example of that)

This is a good post on the topic by basically a Drupal genius. (Not me, I swear)

http://davehall.com.au/blog/dave/2011/05/17/drush-make-and-module-dependencies

Comment: This isn't always advisable, especially for Drupal Install Profiles. See this comment on your linked article http://davehall.com.au/blog/dave/2011/05/17/drush-make-and-module-dependencies#comment-2261

Comment: Ah I wasn't initially clear on him doing this from an install profile! Good point. Thanks for clarifying.